# Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, ppa

```
sudo apt-get update: 
Translation-en Fetched 973 kB in 33s (28,8 kB/s) W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

How do I fix that?

I can't post the entire output here because I don't have 10 points.

Comment: There is a method to the "lameness". I would suggest taking a look at the [about page](http://askubuntu.com/tour) Also, please take a look at [( how to fix 404 when updgrading packages )](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages). There is a nicely detailed diagram discussing the major reasons for 404 issues when updating packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ppa doesn't suport raring, only has support up to precise. You can see it here:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

Remove the ppa from your sources:

```
sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nameoftheppa.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Of course, you'll need to find out what is the "nameoftheppa" to delete it, you can find them all under /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and open them for reading:

```
nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Have a look at the .list files and see which one has network-manager http on it.